# 64-bit Integer vs. 64-bit Float: which one has more values?

Tags: python

Which has more values, a 64-bit integer or a 64-bit float?

My answer is that float has more value because its more accurate.

But isn't integer is always greater than a float ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 .. mantissa-exponent floats are "relative precision"

Comment: If you count a value as each individual configuration of bits, then they have the exact same number of values. That is, they can each hold the same number of bit states.

Comment: this is not a home work this is a past midterm test question. I'm doing it b/c i got exam tomorrow ( yes on a Saturday uoft...)

Comment: My question to you (in response to your last question): Is 1 greater than 1.1 ?

Comment: @Michael: true, but in real terms (i.e. how many real world values map exactly to a distinct bit pattern) the integer "has more". That is to say, if you work back from a bit pattern to the value which produced it you will find there are more such values for the 64bit int because for the IEEE floats there are a number of "invalid" patterns as well as duplicates (+0 and -0).

Comment: @quark: So an integer isn't always greater than a float.

Comment: @jdi my mistake, given the real number line, there exists such values where a floating point number is large than an integer

Comment: @Michael ...but that should be taken with a word of caution when discussing IEEE-754 floating point numbers. There are *multiple representations* for `NaN`, for instance.

Comment: @pst That's why I made sure to be very explicit about my definition of value as bit states. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more *unique values* in a 64-bit integer (2^64 for a two's complement machine).

However, a 64-bit float has *much larger range* of values.

This can be trivially reasoned about because a 64-bit integer *has a unique bit pattern for each unique value* (it is "100% efficient") while a 64-bit float has a dedicated sign bit (which allows for a -0, but [-0 == 0 is true](http://web.archive.org/web/20130808061056/http://www.savrola.com/resources/negative_zero.html)) as well as a few "special patterns" (e.g. `NaN`, which has [multiple representations](http://web.archive.org/web/20130809191748/http://www.savrola.com/resources/NaN.html)) thereby reducing the total number of *unique* values the float can represent.

See the [IEEE-754 article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) and see the sections on the [Representation of non-numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers)

Comment: I like that you emphasized "much larger range" in response to his ambiguous "more values"

Comment: @quark It looks like you are comparing 4-bits to 8-bits (where is the 3-bits? Count the number of binary digits or bit placeholders only). In any case, my answer relates to mantissa-exponent based floating numbers. [BCD or a variant of "packed" decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), as what it looks like is shown in the last comment, are different. Since a 2's complement integer is "100% efficient", the only thing needed to show it can contain more *unique values* than the alternative encoding is to show the alternative is less efficient in some way ;-)

Comment: @quark Floats do not work that way. I suggest your read the article linked in this answer.